# javaFX error en la instalacion para eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx

soy nuevo en la informatica y he instalado javaFX para eclipse, he seguido los pasos para la instalacion y todo parecia ir bien pero al reiniciar eclipse me sale este mensaje

No está ejecutando su instancia de eclipse con Java8. Las herramientas de JavaFX están deshabilitadas debido a esto. Haga de Java8 el sistema java predeterminado o ajuste su eclipse.ini para pasar -vm apuntando a su instalación de Java8.

Agradeceria cualquier ayuda o consejo

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para el vm- es clic derecho sobre la carpeta del proyecto, RUN AS, run configuration, y le da en la pestaña Arguments, donde dice VM Arguments pega esto para windows --module-path "libreria javafx-sdk " --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

entre las comillas va la ruta de la carpeta donde tiene las librerías javafx-sdk